# Energy expectation values in quantum mechanics with the provided spatial wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, measurements

Consider an electron is in a one-dimensional potential well of thickness $$, with infinitely high barriers on either side, and with the potential energy zero at the bottom of the well. The equation of the normalised wave function is
$$
\psi (x) = \sqrt{\frac{105}{2L}} \left( \frac{x}{2L} - \frac{x^3}{2L^3} \right).
$$
Then using the formal method for the energy expectation value, which is integrating the product of the conjugate of the wave function and the Hamiltonian of the wave function with respect to $dx$, and the other method, i.e, using the square of the momentum expectation value, the answer comes out different.

What am I missing here and how am I supposed to find the expectation value of energy with this?

Comment: Are you assuming that $\langle p^2\rangle=\langle p\rangle^2$?

Comment: Better than describing the two methods with words,
would be to actually write the two formulas in your post.
You can use [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for this.

Comment: What is $z$? Did you mean $x$?

Answer (score 1):

The energy expectation value is given as

$E=\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \int dz \psi^{*}(z)H\psi(z)$.

However, I don’t see how this should be related to the momentum expectation value in what you called your “second method”.

Comment: I think the OP means that since in the well $H=p^2/2m$, you can relate average energy to average squared momentum.

Comment: Oh now I see. But the expectation value of the momentum squared obviously isn’t the square of the momentum expectation value.

Comment: @Milarepa you should add that to your answer. Don't leave merely as a comment. And it might not be so obvious to everyone. See if you can easily demonstrate it, either by example or by general rule.

Comment: @BillN I don’t see the need to show that as taking the square is a non-linear operation in the integral for the expectation value

Comment: So If I were to compare this energy with the first energy in an infinite well of tenth L, what should be the answer?, because I’m getting a different answers everytime. Please help me out.

Comment: I would proceed by dividing the integration domain into three subdomains: the two semi-infinte domains where the potential is infinite, left and right to the well of length $L$ and the well itself. However, there is no contribution from the first two integrals as the wavefunction has to be zero outside the well. That’s maybe the point you are missing: the formula you wrote describes the wavefunction in the domain $ 0\leq x \leq L $, while outside of it $\psi(x)=0$. So you need to consider the integral I wrote in the answer from $0$ to $L$ with the $\psi(x)$ you wrote in the question